# Convert a list into a nested Dict

Tags: python

I need to convert a list into a nested Dict in python. Like this:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
value = 5
```

Converted to this:

```
dict = {1: {2: {3: {4: 5}}}}
```

I have already tried

```
new_dict = current = {}
for number in list:
   current[number] = {}
   current = current[number]
```

But how you can see that the value is not in the Dict. How can I fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't name variables `list`, `dict`, or any other built-in name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do:

```
value = 5
my_dict = {}
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
for e in reversed(my_list):
    if not e in my_dict:
        my_dict = {e:value}
        value = {e:value}
```

print(my_dict):

```
{1: {2: {3: {4: 5}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

EDITS : Changed variable name and keyword

1. Not sure what `value` and `new_dict` is used for
2. Never name your variables with a built-in type (don't use `list`)
3. For each number you're creating an empty dictionary and then reassigning `current` to it

   Basically `current[1]={}` followed by `current=current[1]` will obviously always end up with `current={}`

One way to do this :

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

First create just the inner most dictionary with the last element from `myList` and `value`

```
current_dict = {myList[-1]: value}   

new_dict = {}
```

Now loop through each number in the reverse of the list excluding the first one ( 3,2,1)

```
for number in myList[::-1][1:]:
    new_dict[number] = current_dict
    current_dict = new_dict
    new_dict = {}
```

This would look like this :

```
new_dict[3] = {4:5}           | current_dict ={3:{4:5}} 
new_dict[2] = {3:{4:5}}       | current_dict ={2:{3:{4:5}}}
new_dict[1] = {{2:{3:{4:5}}}  | current_dict ={1:{2:{3:{4:5}}}}
```

`current_dict` would have the final result

```
print(current_dict)   #{1: {2: {3: {4: 5}}}}
```

Comment: Just FYI, you should also avoid using `l` as a variable name. See: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid

Comment: `list` is not a keyword.